# How to update a specific child item in an array instead of whole document?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following model.

```
public class Student
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public Prop[] ParentProp {get; set;}
}

public class Prop 
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public ChildProp[] Child {get; set;}
}

public class ChildProp 
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public string Item1 {get; set;}

  public string Item2 {get; set;}

}
```

I want to update just one item in the array instead of whole document.

For example, I need to update second item of ParentProp of 3rd item of Child.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can try this way `Student.ParentProp[1].ChildProp[2]` to get exactly the item you want to update

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
var itemToUpdate = Student.ParentProp[1].ChildProp[2];

itemToUpdate.Item1 = "Updated Name";
```

Keep in mind, C# has [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am trying to update mongo db document.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. Why don't you limit/exlude your data before sending Mongodb ?